# Sails.js E_VALIDATION error

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm starting in sails.js by following a tuto and the sails.js doc .
I'm creating a user account system, when I try to create a new user thru de user form a get this error :

```
{
  "error": "E_VALIDATION",
  "status": 400,
  "summary": "1 attribute is invalid",
  "model": "User",
  "invalidAttributes": {
    "hashedPassword": [
      {
        "rule": "string",
        "message": "`undefined` should be a string (instead of \"null\", which is a object)"
      },
      {
        "rule": "required",
        "message": "\"required\" validation rule failed for input: null"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can see my model below :

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: { type: 'string', required: true },
    username: { type: 'string', required: true },
    email: { type: 'string', lowercase: true, email: true, required: true, unique: true },
    role: { type: 'string', default: 'user' },
    hashedPassword: { type: 'string', required: true },
    provider: 'string',
    salt: 'string',
    facebook: {},
    twitter: {},
    google: {},
    github: {}
  }
};
```

And my controller:

```
module.exports = {

  'new': function(req, res){
    res.view();
  },

  'create': function(req, res, next){
    User.create(req.params.all(), function userCreated(err, user) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      res.json(user);
    });
  }
};
```

Any help please ? thanks

Comment: Can you add the controller code where you're adding the user?

Comment: Since `hashedPassword` is required, are you sure it exists inside `req.params.all()`?

Comment: Yes it exists. HashedPassword has to be required

Comment: Where is the password hashed? and how is it being added back to req.params.all()?

Comment: well, first why you implement the create function by overwriting the default blueprint behavior and adding bugs ? then try to replace your `req.params.all()` with  `req.options.values`